# Resize image function

Tags: jquery, screen

I've got an error in console:

```
TypeError: $("<img/>").attr("src", e.attr("src")) is undefine     
$('<img/>').attr('src', e.attr('src')).load(function(){
```

Here is the whole code of function:

```
function resizeOriginalImg(element, original)
{
var e = jQuery(element);
var newWidth, newHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight, realWidth, realHeight;

$('<img/>').attr('src', e.attr('src')).load(function(){
            realWidth = this.width;   
            realHeight = this.height; 
        });

    if(original)
    {           
        imageWidth = realWidth;   
        imageHeight = realHeight;       
    }

    else
    {
        imageWidth = e.width();
        imageHeight = e.height();
    }   

    if(imageWidth > jQuery(window).width() || imageHeight > jQuery(window).height())
    {
        if(imageWidth >= imageHeight)
        {
            newWidth = jQuery(window).width();
            newHeight = (newWidth/imageWidth)*imageHeight;
        }

        else
        {
            newHeight = jQuery(window).height();
            newWidth = (newHeight/imageHeight)*imageWidth;              
        }
    }       

    e.css({'width' : newWidth, 'height' : newHeight});  
};
```

And:

```
resizeOriginalImg('.current-slide .myimage', true);
```

I don't know what is wrong there, everything seems to be fine, but it doesn't work. Maybe

```
$('<img/>').attr('src', e.attr('src')).load(function()
```

is in bad place and it causes an error?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Syntactically it's fine.  It could be a conflict issue - try replacing `$` with `jQuery`.

Comment: You're next going to come up against the fact that `load()` is non-blocking.

Comment: I've tested the code and am not getting any error. Could you add an example on jsfiddle with css and everything. My example (http://jsfiddle.net/6q2df/) doesn't quite do anything...